# Why some Vue custom component can do `<Radio v-model="today" value="monday" />`?

Tags: vue.js

I was confused by this [boostrap-vue](https://bootstrap-vue.org/docs/components/form-radio)'s `<Radio />` component:

It can do this

```html
<b-form-radio v-model="selected" value="A">Option A</b-form-radio>
```

Why is this happening?

`v-model` is using `value` prop already, why can it still specify `value` prop?

Answer (score 1):

Radio buttons differs a little bit from some other input elements such as text. Radio button values are static (not changing after set) while values on some other field types such as `text` are dynamic (able to change.

So without a `value` on a radio button the `v-model` would not know what data to set.

Read more on: https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/forms.html#Value-Bindings